# Python 3: ValueError: unknown url type

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

Hello I'm running Python 3.9.2 and this is a bit of code I'm trying to run using Cmd Prompt for an assignment to grab anchor tags from a URL.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error<br />
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup<br /><br />
Url = input('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1179927.html')<br />
html = urllib.request.urlopen(Url).read()<br />
Soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')<br />
print(Soup)
```

But I'm running into the current error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br />
  File "C:\Users\BLANK\Desktop\Python 3\SoupTest2.py", line 5, in <module>
    html=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  File "C:\Users\BLANK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\BLANK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 501, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "C:\Users\BLANK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 320, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "C:\Users\BLANK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 346, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Users\BLANK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 375, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: ''
```

Please help. I have noted that this is an assignment. I have edited out the second portion and just left a print statement at the end to test it. I'm still getting the current error.

Comment: `input` expects user input i.e. you put in `'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1179927.html'` at the prompt. Then you need to instantiate the Soup object `Soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`. I don't think there are any `a` tags in response and looking at response this is an homework assignment and should be indicated as such.

Answer (score 0):

this code should work

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import re

info = requests.get("http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1179927.html")

names = re.findall('<tr><td>(.*?)</span></td></tr>',info.text)

#print(names)
my_list_dict = []
for x in names:
    first = "'"+(x.replace('</td><td><span class="comments">',"':'"))+"'"
    print(first)
    my_list_dict.append(first)
```